# Python wtforms - nesting/mixing different field types

Tags: python, wtforms

I'm using wtforms to make a form which contains of RadioFields under which I've got a section of BooleanFields (checkboxes).

Selecting one of the radio fields enables the section under it- probably will be done via jQuery.

My problem is that the radio fields are separate (not binded with each other, have different "name" value, can select all of them). I define them as:

```
foo = RadioField('foo')
bar = RadioField('bar')
```

I've tried using the `choices` parameter on the radio field but I end up with a (properly working) list of radio buttons one after another, with no option to follow the radio button with a couple of checkboxes.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: do you mean the problem with `choices` is that the radio buttons need to be one after another and cannot have checkboxes inserted in between?

Comment: exactly. I need to somehow insert the checkboxes between the radio buttons, but the radio buttons need to keep their features (only one radio button can be selected/active)

Comment: maybe a [FieldList](https://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#wtforms.fields.FieldList)? It has a parameter for `max_entries`.

Comment: FieldList is a list of multiple instances of the same field type and I need to mix the types, or am I not getting this right?

Comment: sorry I haven't used `wtforms` before and that seemed promising based on absolutely no prior knowledge.  I wish you luck finding an answer!